# Can I delete my iPhoto themes folder (/Library/Application Support/iPhoto/Themes)?

Tags: photos.app

I have no interest in ever using them, although I do use iPhoto to store my photos. Will deleting the entire Themes folder mess anything up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found if you leave all the folders starting with *Printing...* and the *Assets* folder that are in the `/Library/Application Support/iPhoto/Themes` folder, you can still print.

Just delete all the other folders and you will regain a chunk of disk space.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to print, so bear that in mind.